# set global sql mode but showing a different mode

Tags: mysql

I have this command to run in my docker file

`mysql -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';"`

But when i check the mysql mode it shows as

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Does anyone has any experience with this ?

Comment: BTW Welcome to the DBA StackExchange !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is quite simple.

When you change the value of a global variable, the current session still retains the session value.

To prove that, please run this

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name='sql_mode'
UNION SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables
WHERE variable_name='sql_mode';
```

You should get this output if the global and session values are the same

```
+---------------+------------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE         |
+---------------+------------------------+
| SQL_MODE      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
```

You should get this output if the global and session values are different

```
+---------------+------------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE         |
+---------------+------------------------+
| SQL_MODE      | STRICT_ALL_TABLES      |
| SQL_MODE      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
```

To see that change, you must logout and login. Then, run the `UNION` query.

If you cannot logout of the current session, you must run

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

to see the difference.

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

## UPDATE 2015-09-03 18:14 EDT

[You just asked me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/set-global-sql-mode-but-showing-a-different-mode/113153?noredirect=1#comment205618_113153)

> Why doesnt it has the STRICT_ALL_TABLES in the global session though ?

Guess what ?? `@@sql_mode` is not global. It's session.

Let me run this query for the difference:

```
mysql> select @@global.sql_mode,@@session.sql_mode,@@sql_mode;
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode | @@session.sql_mode     | @@sql_mode             |
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Therefore, if you want global, you must use `@@global.`. Otherwise, it's session.

Comment: Why doesnt it has the STRICT_ALL_TABLES in the global session though ?

Comment: ```mysql> select @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode      |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```
actually both doesnt show the strict_all_tables

Comment: From your question, you must be running MySQL for Windows. I have MySQL 5.6.22. I have been doing these things from my laptop.

Comment: The problem might be Docker. If Docker is supposed to kickoff `mysql -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';"`, then it hasn't execute it.

Comment: I ran all your commands and mine by hand in MySQL 5.6.22 for Windows and it runs exactly as expected.

Comment: You might be right, Ill investigage further. Thank You Rolando. Ill mark your answer as answered. I gained some insight as the difference in global and session :). Thank You